# How to execute a Zim Database file from command line?

Tags: zim-database

I have a [Zim Database](http://www.zim.biz/) `myfile` file with the content:

```python
output "hello world"
```

I want to execute the file from command line. But, when I try to call `zimmu myfile` from shell, I see the following error:

```
*** Error *** "myfile" is not a know name.
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work, 'myfile' must have been created in directory 'zim' and must be located in zim0001.ws (if compiled).

If not compiled, 'myfile' must be located in the database directory.